# Neural network with 3d numpys as input and linear regression (one output)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, linear-regression

I have already make some linear regression with NN and tensorflow but my input was a pandas dataframe (X_train).
Now I would like to create a neural network with coordinates. I will have X1(x1,y1) and X2(x2,y2) as input. X1.shape: 75, 2, 120  and X2.shape: 75, 2, 120 and y.shape: 75,1

What should be the architecture of the NN network ??
I have tried this:

```py
print('Shape X1:', np.shape(X1))
Shape X1: (75, 2, 120)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(50, input_dim=len(X1[1]), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))
model.summary()

loss = 'mse'
metric = ['mse']                                       
model.compile(loss=loss,
              optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics=metric)
history = model.fit(X1, y, epochs=50, validation_split=0.3, verbose=1)
```

Here is the error i have got:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2 but received input with shape [None, 2, 120]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change input shape. And you have to remove one dimension:

```
import tensorflow as tf
X1 = tf.random.uniform((75, 2, 120))
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, input_shape=(X1.shape[1], X1.shape[2]), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))
model.summary()
```